# Simple basic relative path on file_get_content() function

Tags: php, relative-path

I'm trying to output my `screen.css` file contents with in `<style>` tag.

I thought this was the easy part, but relative path not working?

See my code...

```
<?php printf('<style type="text/css">%s</style>', file_get_contents('css/screen.css?v='.rand()) ); ?>
```

So in theory, this code is in my `index.php`, the relative path should find the css folder local to my php file? But I get this error...

```
Warning: file_get_contents(./css/screen.css?v=1836240868): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in index.php on line 18
');
```

See my folder my structure below...

[image]

If anyone can give me some advice or help on this that would be great.

Comment: Remove it `?v=1836240868` or use `http://` wrapper

Comment: Of course the version was causing it causing it to break, thanks @JessieJackson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Php code

```
define("BASE_URI", "http://example.com/");
```

Html code

```
    <link href="<?php echo BASE_URI;?>/folder/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```